# glm function crashing RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, probability, glm

I am trying to find the probability of a Swinging Strike on a various number of factors, including the count, Release Speed, Spin Rate. I have pitch by pitch data. I changed the value of Pitch Result to 0 and 1 (1 being a Swinging Strike, 0 being others). The dataset includes 380,000+ rows.

Data:

```
str(FastballData1)

'data.frame':   389035 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ GameId           : int  449257 449257 449257 449257 449257 449257 449257 449257 449257 447167 ...
 $ HomeTeamId       : int  108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 ...
 $ AwayTeamId       : int  117 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 118 ...
 $ Inning           : int  1 1 5 1 1 2 1 2 5 4 ...
 $ InningTop        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PlateAppearance  : int  2 2 2 2 2 7 2 7 2 4 ...
 $ PitchOfPA        : int  4 6 1 1 2 4 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ Balls            : int  2 3 0 0 0 2 1 2 0 0 ...
 $ Strikes          : int  1 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 2 0 ...
 $ PitchResult      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BatterId         : int  77171 77171 77171 77171 77171 77171 77171 77171 77171 77171 ...
 $ PitcherId        : int  64271 64271 64271 64271 64271 64271 64271 64271 64271 31921 ...
 $ CatcherId        : int  59270 59270 59270 59270 59270 59270 59270 59270 59270 67658 ...
 $ UmpireId         : int  427248 427248 427248 427248 427248 427248 427248 427248 427248 427156 ...
 $ BatSide          : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ PitchHand        : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ PitcherSet       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Stretch","Windup": 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ PitchType        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Fastball","Slider": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ReleaseSpeed     : Factor w/ 163594 levels "100.003","100.004",..: 118138 113206 96757 105450 108863 104792 99623 88801 106163 118932 ...
 $ PitchTimeToPlate : num  0.409 0.41 0.412 0.415 0.412 ...
 $ SpinAxis         : Factor w/ 176445 levels "-0.389885","-0.468337",..: 105104 92644 108361 90391 102961 103650 106045 109234 109359 123561 ...
 $ SpinRate         : Factor w/ 89264 levels "1002.54","1005.62",..: 51306 60703 54411 46083 47822 32355 50456 49402 47238 44709 ...
 $ HorzBreakPFX     : num  -6.64 -4.49 -7.85 -4.33 -5.69 ...
 $ VertBreakPFX     : num  8.44 9.62 8.92 10.16 7.95 ...
 $ ReleaseHeight    : num  5.48 5.4 5.32 5.51 5.53 ...
 $ ReleaseSide      : num  2.11 2.03 1.82 1.96 2.02 ...
 $ Extension        : num  5.91 6.18 6.45 5.88 6.07 ...
 $ VertApproachAngle: Factor w/ 319725 levels "-0.216948","-0.31733",..: 173138 100071 94338 93526 224459 83541 172155 116761 79538 90746 ...
 $ HorzApproachAngle: Factor w/ 409250 levels "-0.0001026","-0.000107",..: 130394 205101 54294 165802 185810 128876 159926 91503 109419 78589 ...
 $ bscount          : chr  "2-1" "3-2" "0-0" "0-0" ...
```

I am trying to run the following code:

```
glm(PitchResult ~ ReleaseSpeed + bscount + SpinRate, 
data = FastballData1, family = binomial)
```

However, when I do this it shows this code resulting in 96 GB (which is ridiculous) thus causing R Studio to crash. My guess is it seems this creates a circular reference.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Or any other ways to best calculate the probability of a swinging strike based on the above factors?

Comment: Perhaps one of your predictors has many levels?? -- can you add the results of `str(FastballData1)` please

Comment: @user20650 I just edited the post to include it... I have also tried subsetting the data to just included the variables I am looking at and it still crashes.

Comment: okay quick eyeball : `SpinRate` is a factor with 89264 values, and `ReleaseSpeed`     is a factor 163594 levels.This will create 89264 + 163594 new columns when the model matrix is formed. Check that it should be a factor and not numeric.

Comment: There's a bunch actually: `ReleaseSpeed, SpinAxis, SpinRate, VertApproachAngle, HorzApproachAngle`  all should be converted to numeric.

Comment: (ps: it is always good to use `str(yourdata)` after reading in. It lets you check that your data is in the expected form i.e. numeric variables are not factor/character etc)

Comment: someone please post these comments as an answer. There ought to be a canonical duplicate for "I accidentally read numeric values in as a factor, why are weird things happening?" but in the meantime this could be answered ...